# Automating an application running under Wine on Linux

Tags: wine

I have an application (KindleCreate) running under Windows that I would like to automate running it under Wine to integrate with a production workflow. It has very few and simple controls, but in spite of that, Amazon does not offer a command line interface for it. I have been trying the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8869219/how-can-i-find-out-if-an-exe-has-command-line-options) but have not been able to find anything yet.

The operations I would like to perform (and automate) are very simple:

- Control+N
- Choose "Print Replica"
- Choose File (.pdf)
- Select a File
- Edit --> Preserve links
- Ctrl+S (to save the project)
- Ctrl-Shift-P
- Exit

Is this possible? Are there examples anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

*The idea sounds bad but it should work provided the UI is same all the time.*

Use `xdotool`, write a script which will click the buttons and the mouse for you.

```
xdotool --name KindleCreate key ctrl+n mousemove <coodrdinate of 'Print replica'> mouse click 1 ....
```

Read its man page.

Comment: Which idea "sounds bad" the one to automate it or the one to use `xdotool` ? Why so?

Comment: Using `xdotool`, this is not exactly scripting but it works.